# How to override usr bin env perl

Tags: perl, unix

This only checks PATH variable?

Can I "override" path by using say PERL=/usr/somelocal/perl

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Three ways to use a different Perl binary:

1. Set the `PATH` environment variable before executing the script; e.g. `PATH=/opt/alternative-perl/bin:$PATH /path/to/your/script.pl`
2. Execute the Perl binary to use directly and use the script name as its argument: `/opt/alternative-perl/bin/perl /path/to/your/script.pl`
3. If your `$PATH` contains a directory before the one the "bad" Perl binary is located in then you could place a symbolic link to the "good" Perl binary in such a directory. However, this is messy and only applicable in certain situations, but it is a more permanent solution than the first two.

And if you do have write access to that script and you're willing to modify it then @krishnang's reply applies: modify the first line to point to the binary to use, e.g. `#!/opt/alternative-perl/bin/perl`.

Answer (score 0):

You may use this at the beginning of your script:

```
#!/usr/somelocal/perl
```

Refer to [Shebang statement](http://www.sthomas.net/roberts-perl-tutorial.htm/ch22/Shebang)

Answer (score 0):

You can just specify the full path to whichever perl binary you want to use.  **env** is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Three options:

- Don't use `#!` (`/usr/somelocal/perl script.pl`)
- Fix the path (`PATH="/usr/somelocal:$PATH" script.pl`)
- Fix the incorrect `#!`. (`#!/usr/somelocal/perl`)